Lower semicontinuity and epigraph closed (proof without $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument?)
I am reading about convex optimization and one important concept that relates convex functions/functionals to convex sets is the epigraph.
Let $C$ a convex set in a normed space $X$ and $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ a convex functions the epigraph of $f$ is defined as
$$
\text{epi} f := [f,C] = \left\{ (r,x) : x \in C , f(x) \leq r \right\}
$$
An important results states

$f$ lower semincontinuous then the epigraph is closed.

A proof of such result is given in this video however isn't by definition of epigraph
$$
[f,C] = \bigcup_{x \in C} [f(x),+\infty) \times \left\{ x \right\}
$$
if we assume singlentons, like any $x \in C$, is a closed set isn't the epigraph by definition an arbitrary union of closed sets (in the product topology) and therefore arbitrary union of closed is closed? Why is lower semicontinuity essential? what have I done wrong?
Is there a way to prove the theorem without using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ arguments?
A function $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is lower semicontinuous iff for every $r \in \mathbb{R}$ the set
$$
\left\{ x \in X : f(x) > r\right\} = f^{-1}((r,+\infty))
$$
is open. I wonder if by just using the definition I gave of lower semicontinuity and the defintion of $\text{epi } f$ we can get the same result.
My alternative attempt is
$$
[f,C] = \bigcup_{r \in \mathbb{R}} \left\{ r \right\} \times f^{-1}((-\infty,r])
$$
and again each set $\left\{ r \right\}$ is closed and $f^{-1}((-\infty,r])$ is closed (because $f$ is lower semicontinuous).

Arbitrary intersections of closed sets are closed. Arbitrary union of closed sets need not be closed. For example, $$(0,1)=\cup_{x\in (0,1)} {x}$$ is not closed.

That explains the need then. The topology definition reverts between open and closed.

I think we either need to assume that $C$ is the domain of $f$ or that $C$ is closed. Otherwise the epigraph may not be closed.

@user469053 for example?

Take $X=\mathbb{R}$, $C=(0,1)$, $f(x)=x$. The epigraph isn't closed because you can take $(2^{-n}, 2^{-n})_{n=1}^\infty$ converging to $(0,0)$. It's not in the epigraph because $0\notin C$.

We can prove that the epigraph $$[f,C]:=\{(x,r)\in C\times \mathbb{R}:f(x)\leqslant r\}$$ is closed in $C\times \mathbb{R}$. This is not the same thing as showing that it's closed in $X\times \mathbb{R}$ (unless $C$ is closed in $X$). Assume $(x_\lambda, r_\lambda)_{\lambda\in \Lambda}\subset [f,C]$ is a net in $C\times \mathbb{R}$ which converges to $(x,r)\in C\times \mathbb{R}$. By lower semicontinuity of $f$ and the definition of the epigraph, $$f(x)\leqslant \lim\inf_\lambda f(x_\lambda)\leqslant \lim\inf_\lambda r_\lambda =r.$$ Thus $(x,r)\in [f,C]$.
